# Where do I put this phrase in a phrase structure tree?

Tags: phrases, linguistics, syntactic-analysis

I am not sure where to put the AdvP in this sentence when drawing a phrase structure tree.

This is the sentence I would like to create the tree for:
"The car Sam bought last week won the big race."

This sentence has two possible meanings.The meaning I am concentrating on is: '**The car won last week**' (not 'Sam bought the car last week').
Big thanks.

Comment: [[[The] [[car] [Sam bought last week]]] [[won] [[the] [[big] [race]]]].]

Comment: He has said he is considering the sense where "last week" refers to the time of the race, not to the time of Sam's buying the car. Your parsing gives the other sense.

Comment: Hi Jude. I thought that tree might be correct because it has "last week" modifying the verb "won" which is what we want, I think. When did it win? Last week. How would you structure it?  Thanks.

Comment: @JudeN. If that was the intended meaning you would express it as "The car sam bought won the big race last week".  "Last week won the big race" is not an idiomatic way to say it.

Comment: He literally says in the question "The meaning I am concentrating on is: 'The car won last week' (not 'Sam bought the car last week')". I agree this is not the most natural phrase-structure to express that thought; but this is a linguistics question, not a usage question

Comment: @seinfeldesque Just seen this, realise it's out of date now, but, you say "it has "last week" modifying the verb "won"". It doesn't; it has "last week" modifying the verb "bought": "[Sam bought last week]"

Comment: I would add it as an Adjunct to the Verb Phrase "won the big race".

Answer (score 1):

For me, the premise of your question is untrue. "The car Sam bought last week won the big race," is not ambiguous.  If I understand you, you think "last week" can either modify the preceding "bought" or the following "won".  I think it can only modify "bought".

However, there is an adverb that works better for the example: "quickly".  "Sam bought the car quickly" and "The car quickly won" are both acceptable, so "The car Sam bought quickly won the big race" should be ambiguous between

```
"The car Sam [VP bought quickly] won the big race."  
"The car Sam bought [VP quickly won the big race]."
```

Although the written sentence is ambiguous, the two senses are different in intonation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be something like this, putting the "last week" inside the verb phrase spanning "last week won the big race" to indicate the time.

Noun phrases indicating time (e.g., "yesterday", "next month") are usually kept as noun phrase, and are just put next to the verb they modify.

[image: Parse tree of "The car Sam bought last week won the big race"]

(image generated from http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/ with the input `[ROOT [S [NP [NP [DT The] [NN car]] [SBAR [S [NP [NNP Sam]] [VP [VBD bought]]]]] [VP [NP [JJ last] [NN week]] [VBD won] [NP [DT the] [JJ big] [NN race]]]] [. .]]`)

Comment: Thanks justhalf. When I drew up my tree, it was quite similar but I had "The car Sam bought" all under one NP. Would you mind explaining why "Sam bought" needs to go under a separate S? Big thanks, Jo

Comment: Oops, yeah, you are right. "The car Sam bought" should be a noun phrase and the subject of the verb phrase "last week won the big race". The "Sam bought" should be under SBAR in the subject since it is a subordinating clause (a shortened form of "The car **which Sam bought**"). I was using Stanford Parser to generate the original tree and modified from there, but I didn't realize that the whole sentence is parsed as noun phrase. I fixed the tree.

Answer (score 0):

[The car Sam Bought] is a NP functioning as a Subject.
The remaining part is the predicate.

"won" is the head of the verb phrase.

"the big race" is a NP functioning as a DO and complementing the verb.

"last week" is an Adjunct to the Verb Phrase and is positioned to the left.

Using a comma will help to distinguish the meaning you are after. For example:

The car, Sam bought, last week won the big race.

[image: sentence tree]

Answer (score -1):

Under the meaning you have chosen, it is part of the verb phrase "last week won the big race". So it goes beneath this; to the left of the verb "won" and the noun phrase "the big race"